# Does tearing coredata stack will solve model update problem?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

suppose latest app release version is version no 20. and there are 10 coredata migrations so far till version no 20.
and for example: a user which is using version 3. directly do auto update to version no 20.

i want to delete coredata stack and rebuild it then. 
but does it solve that model update issue ? means version 3 uses v3 data model update (xcdatamodel) and version 20 uses v20 data model update(xcdatamodel).
if i delete and rebuild coredata with below code when user autoupdate app from version 3 to 20.
then will it also point to new xcdatamodel version ?

```
 var allstores : Array = self.storeContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores
      for store in allstores{
        // remove store file from coordinator

        do {
          try storeContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator.destroyPersistentStore(at: store.url!, ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, options: nil)

        } catch let error {
          print("\(error.localizedDescription)")

        }
      }
```

and then rebuild..

```
self.storeContainer.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (nsPersistentStoreDescription, error) in
          guard let error = error else {
              return
          }
          fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I implemented this strategy once I decided to rebuild the database when it was incompatible with older versions. Side node: now I just rely on CoreData to handle the migration.

To test if it works, create an entity with a non-mandatory field and insert a row for that entity without a value for that field. Now in your new data model, make that exact same field mandatory. Now what you will see is an app crash if you don't destroy the persistent store and rebuild it, as you are showing in your code. However, if you rebuild it, it will work.

Note that the user has lost all of his data, but I presume you already know that. I had some code that queried the database for existing data and it copied the local cache from the server.

Comment: yeah, i know that user will lost data. But its fine as app is only providing offline caching using coredata. like movie list and all. Not user sensitive data. i was reading blogs, and apple says that if you are using coredata just for cache, then rebuilding coredata stack can be a good idea. instead of going through heavy migrations.